Reoccuring "many connection errors" with AWS Lambda to RDS connection
I was recently caught out using the expired rds-ca-2019 SSL certs on my RDS instance, and the Lambda function that connects to it was logging error messages e.g:

"Host '10.192.21.28' is blocked because of many connection errors;
unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'"

I duly updated the RDS instance to use the rds-ca-rsa2048-g1 bundle, and ran mysqladmin flush-hosts against the DB. The Lambda function was then able to connect to the DB again.
However, the next day, the problem returned. I ran mysqladmin flush-hosts again, and it went away.
It keeps coming back. Not quite every 24 hours, but close to.
What am I missing?
The connection issue is resolved: the Lambda function can connect.
What is causing the  connection errors?
